# 'Tell, Don't Ask' whilst maintaining Separation of Concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, separation-of-concerns

In my Rails app, I have the following association:

- **Video** belongs to **Genre** *(Video does not HAVE to have a genre)*
- **Genre** has many **Videos** *(Genre can have no videos)*

In the Video model, I have the following method.

```
# models/video.rb
def genre_name
    genre.present? ? genre.name : ''
end
```

This is to avoid something like this in the view (which just seems messy):

```
# views/videos/show.html.erb
<% if @video.genre.present? %>
    <%= @video.genre.name %>
<% else %>
    No Genre Present
<% end %>
```

Instead, I can just do this (which looks much tidier)

```
# views/videos/show.html.erb
<%= @video.genre_name %>
```

However, it doesn't feel right asking for information about the genre in the Video model. What's the best way to organise this code? Should I be using helpers instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find yourself doing this kind of thing a lot, it may be worth looking into a decorator pattern, which can house view logic like this. (I quite enjoy using [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) for this purpose, but it's not very difficult to roll your own naive implementation.)

Then, your decorator logic can look like this:

```
class VideoDecorator
  def genre_name
    object.genre.try(:name).presence || "Fallback"
  end
end
```

You can wrap up the model in a decorator as you render in the controller:

```
@video = Video.find(params[:id])
respond_with @video.decorate
```

And your view 'logic' (or lack thereof) can look like this application-wide:

```
<%= @video.genre_name %>
```

Thoughtbot has an excellent explanation of the decorator pattern [here](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/tidy-views-and-beyond-with-decorators)

Comment: I like this since it removes the genre_name method from the Video model.

Answer (score 2):

You could write in your view

```
<%= @video.genre.try(:name) || 'No Genre Present' %>
```

If you don't need the fallback text, just

```
<%= @video.genre.try(:name) %>
```

[Read more about `Object#try` here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try).

If you want the fallback also when `name` is an empty string (not just `nil`) you can use [`Object#presence`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence)

```
<%= @video.genre.try(:name).presence || 'No Genre Present' %>
```

Comment: This is very nice. I particularly like the first example :) Thanks.

Comment: I wonder, however, if there's a way to do this without putting logic in the view?